# R ggplot histogram Bins vs python numpy histogram Bins

Tags: python, r, numpy, ggplot2, histogram

I have created a histogram using ggplot and numpy. I used bins=30 on both modules but each shows a different graph. What is causing the difference, and how would I resolve it?

Snippet of ggplot code:

***NOTE***: ggplot_histogram uses default bins=30

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "column_name")) +
         geom_histogram(aes(fill = ..count..))
```

[image: ggplot histogram graph]

Snippet of numpy python code:

```
hist, edges = np.histogram("column_name", bins=30)
```

[image: numpy histogram graph]

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by supplying a toy dataset.

Comment: `geom_histogram` calculates bins and converts them to a factor. When you plot a factor, it is plotted centered around that factor tick. numpy appears to be using a different approach and draws values between two ticks. Which is best? Probably depends on whom you ask.

Comment: Just because you have the same number of bins doesn't mean the boundaries between the bins are in the same places.  You could try adding the argument `boundary = 0` when calling `geom_histogram`.